# Try/Except in Python: appropriate for parsing dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a dictionary containing nested lists and dictionaries. I'm trying to detect if a given key is present and save it's value to an appropriate variable. The below code works but feels incredibly messy. Is there a right/better way of handling this?

```
def wit_response(self, message_text=None):
    if message_text is not None:
        resp = self.client.message(message_text)
        print(resp)

        try:
            intent = resp['entities']['intent'][0]['value']
        except:
            intent = None
        try:
            location = resp['entities']['location'][0]['value']
        except:
            location = None
        try:
            datetimefrom = resp['entities']['datetime'][0]['values'][0]['from']['value']
        except:
            datetimefrom = None
        try:
            datetimeto = resp['entities']['datetime'][0]['values'][0]['to']['value']
        except:
            datetimeto = None
```

Example of what resp might look like.

> {u'entities': {u'intent': [{u'confidence': 0.99699357488585, u'value': u'weather'}], u'location': [{u'suggested': True, u'confidence': 0.87101, u'type': u'value', u'value': u'like'}]}, u'msg_id': u'0jkzwqMkSkpZsKJYx', u'_text': u'What is the weather like?'}

Comment: Looks fine to me. I don't think there is a less messy way of doing this.

Comment: Do you mean want a concise method to do that?

Comment: I guess I'm used to using switch statements and checking for nulls or something like that. Is this really an appropriate way of doing this in python? I'm a bit worried that this will be a very large block of try/except as I add to it. If there's a more concise method, I'd love to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get much shorter without using some sort of helper function or new container. One way is to write a function:

```
def try_get(obj, key):
    if not key:
        return obj

    key, _, rest = key.partition('.')

    try:
        key = int(key)
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        return try_get(obj[key], rest)
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

And use it like so:

```
intent = try_get(resp, 'entities.intent.0.value')
location = try_get(resp, 'entities.location.0.value')
datetimefrom = try_get(resp, 'entities.datetime.0.values.0.from.value')
datetimeto = try_get(resp, 'entities.datetime.0.values.0.to.value')
```

JSON doesn't allow integer dictionary keys, so this should unambiguously allow you to traverse any object parsed from JSON.